# Integer instance and int primitive value comparison in Java

Tags: java

```
Integer a = 5;
int b = 5;

System.out.println(a==b); // Print true
```

But why does this print true, since a is an instance of an `Integer` and b is a primitive `int`?

Comment: This feature is more than 10 years old, so it is surprising that this doesn't appear anywhere on the internet ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Java does not see that Integers are equal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428774/why-java-does-not-see-that-integers-are-equal)

Comment: Here is a very interesting question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024933/why-equal-operator-works-for-integer-value-until-128-number

Comment: @AadityaGavandalkar:  No, that's definitely *not* a duplicate of *that* question.

Comment: @awsome:  It's interesting, but it's unrelated to this scenario.

Comment: that is right but just to make you aware of something interesting about Integer equality

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Java uses the concept of `Unboxing` when you compare primitive and wrapper class. Where in a `Integer` variable is translated into primitive `int` type.

Following is what is happening with your code:

```
Integer a = 5; //a of type Integer i.e. wrapper class
int b = 5; //b of primitive int type

System.out.println(a==b) // a is unboxed to int type and compared with b, hence true
```

For more on `Autoboxing`(reverse of Unboxing) and `Unboxing` [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) link.

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer is due to unboxing, but let's be more explicit here.

The rules for numerical equivalence are described [in the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1), specifically these rules:

> If the operands of an equality operator are both of numeric type, or one is of numeric type and the other is convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric type, binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).

Since `Integer` is convertible to a numeric type (per [these rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)), the values you're comparing become semantically equivalent to `a.intValue() == b`.

It should be stressed that this conversion will *fail* if `a` is `null`; that is, you will get a `NullPointerException` when attempting to do that equivalence check.

Answer (score 3):

Beginning with JDK 5, Java added two important features: **autoboxing and auto-unboxing.**

> Autoboxing is the process by which a primitive type is automatically
>   encapsulated (boxed)  into its equivalent type wrapper whenever an
>   object of that type is needed. There is no need to explicitly
>   construct an object.
>
> Auto-unboxing is the process by which the value of a boxed object is
>   automatically extracted (unboxed) from a type wrapper when its value 
>   is needed.

With autoboxing, it is no longer necessary to manually construct an object in order to 
wrap a primitive type:

```
Integer someInt = 100; // autobox the int (i.e. 100) into an Integer
```

To unbox an object, simply assign that object reference to a primitive-type variable:

```
int unboxed = someInt // auto-unbox Integer instance to an int
```

Answer (score 1):

Here all the post answer are correct.

Here your code at Compile time

```
public class Compare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Integer a=5;
        int b=5;

        System.out.println(a==b);
        //the compiler converts the code to the following at runtime: 
        //So that you get it at run time
        System.out.println(a==Integer.valueOf(b));


    }
```

}