# Very Wired thing happens when I compare two elements of the ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    myList.add(2000);
    myList.add(2000);
    myList.add(2);
    myList.add(2);

    if(myList.get(1)==myList.get(0))System.out.println("2000 equal check");
    if(myList.get(1)!=myList.get(0))System.out.println("2000 not equal check");
    if(myList.get(2)==myList.get(3))System.out.println("2 equal check");
    if(myList.get(2)!=myList.get(3))System.out.println("2 not equal check");
}
```

My code is shown above. And the results are shown below.

2000 not equal check

2 equal check

[The results show me very wired things..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfOz5.png)

I am really confused... I appreciate if somebody can help me with this.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You shall not compare reference types (anything that is an Object) using ==. Always use equals().

== returns true if the two Object references are pointing to the  **same** object in memory.

Given that, the problem is how the Integer objects come into existence:

while working on your source code the compiler does different things for
add(2000) and add(2):

For values between -127 and 128 ... the compiler will actually not create a new Integer object, but do some "smart" caching ... so add(2) always adds the SAME object instance.

Therefore the reference-equality check using == returns true. For add(2000), a new object is returned each time; therefore == returns false.

Comment: "`new Integer(2) == new Integer(2) ` will always be TRUE" say ***WHAT***? [No it doesn't, that expression always returns FALSE] You'd better try that and then rewrite your answer.

Comment: Note:  `new Integer(2)` is also *not* what happens when the OP does `myList.add(2);`

Comment: You are correct; seems like I was half asleep when writing that down yesterday. Fixed; thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are working with `Integer` objects and thus, you should use `.equals()`.

```
if(myList.get(1).equals(myList.get(0)))
     System.out.println("2000 equal check");
if(!myList.get(1).equals(myList.get(0)))
     System.out.println("2000 not equal check");
// works because of: see link in the comments to your question
if(myList.get(2)==myList.get(3))System.out.println("2 equal check");
if(myList.get(2)!=myList.get(3))System.out.println("2 not equal check");
```

[The link from the comment section of your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024933/why-equal-operator-works-for-integer-value-until-128-number)